# Difference between []uint8 && []byte (Golang Slices)

Tags: go

One of the functions I am running: image.Decode()

The image.Decode function takes in an io.Reader && and the io.Reader function takes in a []byte.

When I pass in a []uint8, if gives me this error:

```
panic: image: unknown format
```

How do I convert the []uint8 to []byte?

UPDATE

The error is happening at the starred area because image.Decode can't read the variable xxx.

```
    package main

    import (
        "github.com/nfnt/resize"
        "image"
        "image/jpeg"
        "fmt"
        "launchpad.net/goamz/aws"
        "launchpad.net/goamz/s3"
        "bytes"
        "encoding/json"
        "io/ioutil"
        "os"
        "reflect"
    )

    type Data struct {
        Key string
    }

    func main() {

      useast := aws.USEast

      connection := s3.New(auth, useast)
      mybucket := connection.Bucket("bucketName")

      image_data, err := mybucket.Get("1637563605030")

      if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
      } else {
        fmt.Println("success")
      }

      xxx := []byte(image_data)

      ******* THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS **************

      original_image, _, err := image.Decode(bytes.NewReader(xxx))

      ******* THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS END **************

      if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Shit")
        panic(err.Error())
      } else {
        fmt.Println("Another success")
      }

      new_image := resize.Resize(160, 0, original_image, resize.Lanczos3)

      if new_image != nil {
        fmt.Println("YAY")
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide image and code example? I don't think []uint8 is the issue, e.g. this works: http://play.golang.org/p/PXxN-iLeuB

Answer (score 62):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Numeric types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> ```
> uint8       the set of all unsigned  8-bit integers (0 to 255)
>
> byte        alias for uint8
> ```

---

```
package main

import "fmt"

func ByteSlice(b []byte) []byte { return b }

func main() {
    b := []byte{0, 1}
    u8 := []uint8{2, 3}
    fmt.Printf("%T %T\n", b, u8)
    fmt.Println(ByteSlice(b))
    fmt.Println(ByteSlice(u8))
}
```

Output:

```
[]uint8 []uint8
[0 1]
[2 3]
```

---

You have misdiagnosed your problem.

Comment: You can also just use it directly: `[]byte([]uint8{uint8(2), uint8(3)})`

Answer (score 7):

As the other answers have explained, there's no problem passing a `[]uint8` where a `[]byte` is required. If this was your problem, you'd be getting a compile time error. You aren't. A panic is a runtime error, and it's being thrown by the image library when it reads the data in the slice.

In fact, the image library is only partially your problem. See http://golang.org/src/pkg/image/format.go. It's returning an error message because it doesn't recognize the image format of the data in the slice. Your code, which calls `image.Decode()` is calling `panic` when `image.Decode()` returns the error message.

Comment: @JorgeOlivero you must have stored something that wasn't an image (or wasn't in a format that the Go library recognizes) in that bucket in S3.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a variable `imageData` that is `[]uint8` you may pass `[]byte(imageData)`

See http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions